# Add hyperlink to DocuSign envelope programatically

Tags: java, sdk, docusign-sdk

I am using the DocuSign Java SDK to create the whole envelope programmatically.
Is there a way to add a clickable hyperlink in the envelope?

Adding the hyperlink in the document pdf itself is not an option since the hyperlink won't be clickable while signing (it will be just visible on the background).

I know it is possible to create custom field and use it in a template like described [here](https://support.docusign.com/s/articles/How-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-DocuSign?language=en_US),
but in my case I am not using templates.

I tried to create Text field programmatically like below and put it in the envelope, but the link is not clickable when the document is being reviewed. Is there a way to make it clickable while the signing (i.e. when the client opens the document in DS)

```
        Text asd = new Text()
        .name("#HREF_TermsAndConditions")
        .value("https://thelink")
        .required("true")
        .tooltip("https://thelink")
        .documentId("1")
        .pageNumber("1")
        .xPosition("100")
        .yPosition("600");
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to set TabLabel to #HREF_TermsAndConditions for it to appear a hyperlink.
name should be set to the target url

```
Text asd = new Text()
    .tabLabel("#HREF_TermsAndConditions")
    .name("https://thelink")
    .required("true")
    .tooltip("https://thelink")
    .documentId("1")
    .pageNumber("1")
    .xPosition("100")
    .yPosition("600");
```